# XML output to HTML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML (Simplified)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REPOSITORY>
<VIEW UPDATED_BY="SADMIN">
    <VIEW_LOCALE  UPDATED_BY="SADMIN">  </VIEW_LOCALE>
    <VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE UPDATED_BY="SADMIN" COMMENTS="TEST COMMENT">
        <VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM UPDATED_BY="SADMIN"></VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM>
        </VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE>
    </VIEW>
<VIEW UPDATED_BY="USER">
    <VIEW_LOCALE  UPDATED_BY="USER">    </VIEW_LOCALE>
    <VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE UPDATED_BY="USER">
        <VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM UPDATED_BY="USER"></VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM>
        <VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM UPDATED_BY="USER2"></VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM>
        </VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE>
    </VIEW>
</REPOSITORY>
```

I need to traverse this XML and print the output as HTML Tables. Below is the XSL I have come up with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match ="/" >
<html><head></head>
<body>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/" >
<xsl:for-each select="REPOSITORY/VIEW">
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>Updated By</td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="@UPDATED_BY" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<xsl:if test="./VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Updated By</td><td>Comments</td></tr>
       <xsl:for-each select="*[name()='VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE']">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@UPDATED_BY" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@COMMENTS" /></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each> <!-- end of view_web_template -->     
    </table>
    <xsl:if test="./VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM">
        <table>
        <tr><td>Updated by</td></tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="./VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM">
                <tr> 
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@UPDATED_BY" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each> <!-- end of web_template_item -->
        </table>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each> <!-- end of view -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know this might not be the best way to do it but I am not able to get the **VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM** node data in table. The if condition fails.

I suspect that it might due the fact that **VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE** node has already been processed due to for-each.

So my XPATH should be *if previously processed node has child then select it* but I am not expert enough in XSLT to be able to do that.
Any pointers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT doesn't care (or keep track of) which nodes have been processed. It is perfectly valid to select and process the same nodes several times.

The problem in this case is one of context. The first and second `xsl:if` statements have the same XSLT context, namely a `VIEW` element. But to match a VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM element, the context has to be a VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE element. From a purely technical point of view, all you need to do is write `<xsl:if select="VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE/VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE_ITEM">`, and the condition will be true.

That said, in your particular case, I guess you will want to move the second condition inside the `<xsl:for-each>`. Then it will be in the correct context anyway, since the `<xsl:for-each>` processes VIEW_WEB_TEMPLATE elements.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I couldn't use it inside for-each as it needs to be independent table. So I changed the if and select clause.